# Using systemd to prevent python scripts from crashing

Tags: systemd, python, raspberry-pi, autostart

I want to prevent multiple python scripts from crashing on my Raspberry Pi (Stretch OS).

I wanted to clarify if this would be the way of implementing a systemd file to prevent **multiple** **python** scripts from crashing. Under the service section of the service file, the typical format is:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/path/too/script
Restart=always
```

But since I am running **multiple python** scripts, I think I should add python to the front of the path, as well as stacking service section on top of each other. Please correct me if I am wrong.

My current script (constantrun.service) is:

```
[Unit]
Description='python scripts that needs to be run constantly'

[Service]
ExecStart=python /home/pi/projects/script1.py
Restart=always
[Service]
ExecStart=python /home/pi/projects/script2.py
Restart=always
[Service]
ExecStart=python /home/pi/projects/script3.py
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

However, when I run try to start this service file with `sudo systemctl start constantrun.service`. I get the following error:

```
Failed to start constantrun.service: Unit constantrun.service is not loaded properly: Invalid argument.
See system logs and 'systemctl status constantrun.service' for details.
```

I open the log, and I see:

```
● constantrun.service - 'python scripts that needs to be run constantly'
   Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Feb 18 17:15:12 raspberrypi systemd[1]: [/lib/systemd/system/constantrun.service:11] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: python /home/pi/P
Feb 18 17:15:12 raspberrypi systemd[1]: constantrun.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
Feb 18 17:20:17 raspberrypi systemd[1]: [/lib/systemd/system/constantrun.service:5] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: python /home/pi/Pr
Feb 18 17:20:17 raspberrypi systemd[1]: [/lib/systemd/system/constantrun.service:8] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: python /home/pi/Pr
Feb 18 17:20:17 raspberrypi systemd[1]: [/lib/systemd/system/constantrun.service:11] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: python /home/pi/P
Feb 18 17:20:17 raspberrypi systemd[1]: constantrun.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
Feb 18 17:20:33 raspberrypi systemd[1]: [/lib/systemd/system/constantrun.service:5] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: python /home/pi/Pr
Feb 18 17:20:33 raspberrypi systemd[1]: [/lib/systemd/system/constantrun.service:8] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: python /home/pi/Pr
Feb 18 17:20:33 raspberrypi systemd[1]: [/lib/systemd/system/constantrun.service:11] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: python /home/pi/P
Feb 18 17:20:33 raspberrypi systemd[1]: constantrun.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
```

How can I modify the code above to get it working? Also, do I need to add a path to my python library such as`PYTHONPATH=/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`?

I am really new to the linux environment, and would appreciate any advice on this!

Comment: The best way to prevent a script from crashing is to not let it crash in the first place. What do you want to achieve here?

Comment: @pfnuesel: I have two python scripts that read/write a text file. Most of the time, they work fine simultaneously. However, occasionally, either one of them can crash, and I think that is because one is writing while the other is reading the text file. This only occurs when the read/write processes from both scripts coincide, which is not very often. Hence, I thought of trying an approach so that either python scripts can still pick itself up and continue running even after such an error.

Comment: They crash when script#1 is trying to read not-yet written text of script#2... ...or something like that? Edit to pause the script which depends on non existing text so that after every 2 rows it sleeps for 120 seconds or so - you'll have to fiddle with this timing on your own to see what works best for you.

Comment: @Fido-X: Thanks, that is a good idea. Do you think I could potentially modify the relevant script with `try: #reads txt file....` followed by `except:time.sleep(2)`. Would this be a feasible approach?

Comment: @Craver2000 add the following between lines:  
import time
time.sleep(120) # To pause for 2 minutes

Comment: @Craver2000, if I understand you correctly, one script is a producer and one is a consumer. Is this correct, or do they communicate between each other? Are there any other dependencies between the two scripts? If it's a strict producer/consumer relationship, piping the output from one to the other might be a better solution.

Comment: @ErikF: They communicate with each other through this text file. Initially, I used the python import approach, but came into problems due to circular imports (variables not relaying properly to the other script), so I've used the text file method as an intermediary between the two. I've also used the text file method because I liked that the last variable generated is stored even after I shut off the device, ready for use when I switch on the device.

Comment: @Craver2000 in that case, I would suggest [using a file lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489861/locking-a-file-in-python) while you're writing to the file. It's less prone to failure!

Comment: I agree with the commenters above that you should fix the synchronization problem in your scripts, and not try to sweep them under the carpet using systemd. Having said that, what systemd is complaining about is that you haven't specified an absolute path to the python interpreter in the unit file. The absolute path to the script is not enough, you need the path to the python binary as well, something like `/usr/bin/python`.

Comment: @ErikF: Thanks for the suggestion. In that case, I think I can use the filelock method just before reading from the text file, in the relevant part of my scripts. That way, it prevents simultaneous writing of the file during/just before reading.

Comment: @JohanMyréen: The path to the python binary that you are referring to, would it suffice if I add a single line: `PYTHONPATH=/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` to the top of the service section?

Comment: Personally I would avoid systemd altogether and use FreeBSD.

Comment: @Rob:Is that another type of OS? I'm currently using Raspberry Pi, so my OS is limited to Debian.

Comment: @Craver2000 FreeBSD is a direct descendant of ATT Unix and runs Netflix, WhatsApp, Juniper Networks, Sony Playstation, and much, much more. It also runs on Raspberry Pi so, no, your OS choice is not limited to Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Your service definitions are like this:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=python /home/pi/projects/script1.py
Restart=always
```

And this is the error message on each of them:

```
Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: python /home/pi/...
```

For `systemd`, the "executable" in this service definition is `python`, and that is clearly not an absolute path. The `/home/pi/projects/script1.py` is just an argument to this `python` executable, and caring about its proper form is the executable's job.

Any Python-specific environment variables like `PYTHONPATH` have no meaning at all for `systemd`: you **must** give it an absolute path for the executable in the service definition, each and every time.

Typically, the absolute path to the python interpreter is `/usr/bin/python`, but you can check:

```
$ type python
python is /usr/bin/python
```

So your service definitions should be like this:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/pi/projects/script1.py
Restart=always
```

A very useful introduction to systemd can be found here. It gets and keeps a telegram bot running as a python script.

- https://iltabiai.github.io/raspberry%20pi/python/linux/ubuntu/telegram/2020/05/08/python-systemd.html

Comment: Mine is python 3.5, Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS requires this, while Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)  doesn't